# How to compare for two different objects inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

What is the best way to compare two different objects for equality inside of ng-repeat, why doesn't angular.equals work for me here:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.filteredItems" ng-class="{'active':angular.equals(row,ctrl.ngModel), 'focus': angular.equals(row,ctrl.focusedRow)}">
      <td ng-repeat="value in ctrl.sort(row) track by $index" class="text-center">
            {{value}}
      </td>
</tr>
```

I want to add the active class if the current row and the pre-selected row coming from the controller match.

Comment: You want to add to add some logic. Better not do that in the view, but in the controller. There you compare values and only pass the values you want to the view.

Comment: I need to compare with each row though in ng-repeat. How would I do the above in a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function in JS which will do angular.equals(obj1, obj2) and use this function to check is it active or not?

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.filteredItems" ng-class="{'active': checkEqualiy(row, ctrl.ngModel), 'focus': checkEquality(row,ctrl.focusedRow)}">
  <td ng-repeat="value in ctrl.sort(row) track by $index" class="text-center">
        {{value}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$scope.checkEquality= function(param1, param2){
   return angular.equals(param1, param2)
}
```